# how to decode bson in cyrillic?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, python-3.5, bson, cyrillic

i got a bson

`{'room': '55d5928a4d02f4a55007344c', 'sender': '55af71054d02f4571abe1f1f', 'message': 'Ð\x9fÑ\x80Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ\x82! Ð\x97Ð´ÐµÑ\x81Ñ\x8c Ð²Ñ\x8b Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑ\x82Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð´Ð°Ñ\x82Ñ\x8c Ð²Ð¾Ð¿Ñ\x80Ð¾Ñ\x81 Ð¸ Ð±Ñ\x8bÑ\x81Ñ\x82Ñ\x80Ð¾ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ñ\x83Ñ\x87Ð¸Ñ\x82Ñ\x8c Ð¾Ñ\x82Ð²ÐµÑ\x82 Ð½Ð° Ð½ÐµÐ³Ð¾.', 'created_at': 1440146705.612493, '_id': ObjectId('55d6e5114d02f49f998a08b5')}`

and i want to get 'message' out of it in python3. how do i decode it?

I already tried this 

`raw.encode().decode('utf8')
raw.encode().decode('cp1251')`

but it gives bad result

`'ГђВџГ‘ВЂГђВёГђВІГђВµГ‘В‚! ГђВ—ГђВґГђВµГ‘ВЃГ‘ВЊ ГђВІГ‘В‹ ГђВјГђВѕГђВ¶ГђВµГ‘В‚ГђВµ ГђВ·ГђВ°ГђВґГђВ°Г‘В‚Г‘ВЊ ГђВІГђВѕГђВїГ‘ВЂГђВѕГ‘ВЃ ГђВё ГђВ±Г‘В‹Г‘ВЃГ‘В‚Г‘ВЂГђВѕ ГђВїГђВѕГђВ»Г‘ВѓГ‘В‡ГђВёГ‘В‚Г‘ВЊ ГђВѕГ‘В‚ГђВІГђВµГ‘В‚ ГђВЅГђВ° ГђВЅГђВµГђВіГђВѕ.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is UTF-8 which has been improperly decoded as Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1).

```
>>> raw.encode('l1').decode()
"{'room': '55d5928a4d02f4a55007344c', 'sender': '55af71054d02f4571abe1f1f', 'message': 'Привет! Здесь вы можете задать вопрос и быстро получить ответ на него.', 'created_at': 1440146705.612493, '_id': ObjectId('55d6e5114d02f49f998a08b5')}"
```